# wrong DNS resolution

Tags: networking, server, dns, display-resolution, resolv.conf

I have 2 servers with similar configuration but one of them give me different result from a nslookup command

The first one is working correctly and here is the answer I have:

```
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   vdemopro1260sha.xxxcom
Address: 58.246.89.xx
```

On the other one, the same command give me a wrong address (in fact this address is the server IP address).

```
[ansiuser@vrdopsxxdsy terminator]$ nslookup vdemopro1330sha.xxx.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   vdemopro1330sha.xxx.com
Address: 10.91.78.xx
```

The /etc/resolv.conf file is the same for both servers

```
search  dmz.ap.3ds.com dsone.3ds.com ds
nameserver      10.91.78.5
nameserver      10.91.78.6
```

I don't understand what is causing differences in behaviour. Is someone has an idea?
Thanks

Comment: The second server gets a private address. It is OK, if it is in the same private network.

Comment: I do not understand your question. In the first case, you ask about vdemopro1260sha.xxx.com, and in the second - about vdemopro1330sha.xxx.com. They are different names (FQDNs) and therefore you may get a different answers. There is nothing abnormal about this. Each of the two public DNS records can contain any address that the domain administrator places there. Try using `dig` to ask your internal DNS server instead of the public Goggle DNS server. `dig vdemopro1260sha.xxx.com @10.91.78.5` and `dig vdemopro1330sha.xxx.com @10.91.78.5`.